# Dojo filteringSelect query expression

Tags: regex, filtering, dojo

I'm using the dojo filtering select widget. I'm trying to customize the queryExpr. According to all forums/documentation, there are 4 types of expressions:
 - ${0} - find exact expression
 - *${0}* - contains
 - ${0}* - starts with
 - *${0} - ends with

I'm trying to accomplish an auto-completion where any word starts with the typed in string. For example:

if I type "expr" the following suggestion will pop up "some expression".

The contains expression doesn't really do the job, because I don't want that suggestion to appear if I type "press" for example.

Does the queryExpr attribute accept regular expressions?
If not, is there any way of achieving this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The auto-completion functionality in `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` is derived from `dijit.form.ComboBox`.

You could extend `dijit.form.ComboBox`, override the `_autoCompleteText()` function, providing your custom implementation.

Finally, you could then create your own custom filtering select control that inherited from your custom combo box instead of the `ComboBox`.

[Writing Custom Widgets Quickstart Guide](http://docs.dojocampus.org/quickstart/writingWidgets?highlight=%28widget%29|%28custom%29)

Answer (score 0):

The functionality explained in the question is available for diji.form.FilteringSelect widget by default. The 'contains' is not checked for, rather it is checked for the matches from the beginning of the text as expected by you.